# how to repeatedly stop and restart a command

Tags: bash, timeout, watch

I'm trying to find a simple way to  repeatedly restart a command after a certain time (let's say 10 seconds for the purpose of this question). For simplicity let's say the command in question is `htop --tree`.

My attempt so far: To just run and then stop a command *once* I found the commmand `timeout`, so `timeout 10 htop --tree` runs the command and stops it again after 10 seconds. To repeat that I found the command `watch` which lets you rerun a command every given time interval. So my attempt was combining the two using

```
watch -n 10 `timeout 9 htop --tree`
```

but then it the output of `htop` does not show up. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong or how to fix that, or suggest an alternative bash solution for what I'm trying to achive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the `watch` utility affects the way some commands work. It would better to just use a loop.  It also seems as if you are requesting to watch the *output* of the `htop` command, as a command, which is probably not what you actually want (just spotting those backticks, which is a command substitution, meaning that that part of the command will be replaced by the output of the command within).

```
while true; do
    timeout 10 htop --tree
done
```

Depending on the effect that you want to achieve, you may also want to investigate the update delay in `htop` itself.  Here, I use a 10 second refresh rate:

```
htop -d 100
```

(the delay is measured in tenths of a second)

Comment: I completely forgot about the loops in bash, thank you very much! Thanks for the tip with `htop`, I only used it as an example comman but it is nice to know it also has this argument!